# Explanation about Firebase Connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the docs, Firebase is supposed to have one concurrent per device. My Firebase dashboard is showing multiple concurrent but my app is in development mode and I am the only one using the database, on a single emulator.

[image: Firebase Multiple Concurrent connections]

How come one device is resulting in 11 concurrent connections?